# Detect CloseEvent through different forms

Tags: c#, winforms

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

**SHORT STORY**

I want to detect "FormClosing()" event through different forms, ie, when form1 is closed that is instantiated within form2, can form2 detect when user presses exit in form1?

**LONG STORY**

My team and I are working on a windows form application. Project has two forms: one is the main form page and the other is accessed via this main form. Main form looks like this:

[image: Main Form]

And the second one looks like this:

[image]

If you press "Ekle/Sil" buttons within the main form, you are directed to form 2 where you can edit database entries. When you press "Sayfayı Yenile" button in the main form, the content of the text areas are refreshed by re-fetching entries from the database.

My problem is, I want to automatically refresh the main form when the user closes the second form. My research suggests I should use an "FormClosing()" event to detect a closing form. However, I want to detect this from the main form. Instantiating main form in second form's source code doesn't seem to be a reliable solution. Anyone can tell me how to do this?

**EDIT**

I solved the problem:
1) Created a public method within the main form that refreshes the page.
2) Send "this" property from the main form when creating the second form.
3) Added an "FormClosed()" handler within the second form that invokes this public method.

Still, I'm looking for a better solution.

**EDIT 2**

Better solution [InBetween's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45099598/6922712)

Comment: Depending on your needs you should use [`FormClosed`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed(v=vs.110).aspx) which will be called after the form was closed or [`FormClosing`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing(v=vs.110).aspx) which will be called before form is closed and you can alternatively cancel the closing event in there.

Comment: Is the second form opened using `ShowDialog()`?  If so, can you just have your other code follow on, without the need to watch events?

Comment: No, second form is instantiated and made visible by saying "form.Show()"

Comment: 1) Send parentform as reference into childform in constructor 
`public ChildForm(ParentForm parent)` 
2) Subscribe on childform's `onClose` event in parentForm

Comment: Eventhough i didnt want to do it, this KamikyIT's suggestion solved my problem. Sadly, I had to use a public method where it should be private.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the `Form.Closed` event of the new child windows form. Everything is handled from the main form:

```
void EkleSil_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) //or whatever method is called when button is clicked
{
     var newChildForm = new ChildForm();
     newChildForm.Closed += childFormClosed;
     newChildForm.Show();
}

void childFormClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ((Form)sender).Closed -=childFormClosed;
     updateShownData();
}
```

Comment: Why I did not see this earlier? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a event in the second form and raise it when the form is closing . 
Handle the event in the main form and refresh the main form when the event is raised

Comment: Why create a new event when you have such events : `FormClosing`, `FormClosed` ?

Comment: Yes . Thats also a Solution

Comment: How can I handle that event from form1 if its triggered within form2? How can this link can be installed?

Comment: You must have the child form object in the main form . Use that object to add a event handler in the main form

Comment: So, if I define a private form object in the main form like a global variable and instead of locally create an instance of second form, assigning a second form instance to this variable allows me to handle that event?

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to pass Form1 as an argument to Form2. Then use the Form.Closing event in Form2 and use the Form1 reference to trigger something.

```
Form1 form1Ref;

public Form2(Form1 mainform)
{
     form1Ref = mainform;
}

private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
     form1Ref.SomeMethod();
}
```